# The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http' - basicHttpBinding with HTTPs not working

Tags: wcf

I've a wcf config as shown below and I'm trying the run the service on https.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicHttps">
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Username" />
              <message />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          bindingNamespace="http://mydomain.com" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttps"
          name="basicTest" bindingNamespace="http://mydomain.com"
          contract="IMyContract" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
              membershipProviderName="MySqlMembershipProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**WCFSTORM** error out with this:
*

> *The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.*

- Could someone please help me point out my bug on above config please?

I also tried with this but same error:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicHttps">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
              <message />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

My Service Class looks like below:

```
namespace Service
{
    [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, Namespace = "http://mydomain.com")]
    class MyService : IMyContract
    {

    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks @degorolls howing on windows Azure. I get this message from visual studio:
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Comment: Do have HTTPS binding enabled in your hosting environment? How are you hosting this for development? I always try to get everything running in local IIS first.

Comment: What is the full name (including namespaces) of your service class?

Comment: Hi @Ladislav Mrnka, I've updated my query below with service class.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all who put some comments on my question. finally I figured out myself. The config was all OK.

The problem was with WCF Storm, the Authentication Type should be set to NONE on Config dialog (WCF STORM).

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

or use wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding and no need to change something on WCFStorm side